# AutoLayout frame size changing between functions

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I'm currently creating a custom set of views to form a list. However, I'm having an issue with AutoLayout.

It appears the size of the views are changing in between function calls. Here's some of the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.scrollView layoutIfNeeded];

    self.contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, 50.0f)];

    [self.contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.scrollView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.contentView];

    [self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[contentView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:@{@"contentView":self.contentView}]];
    [self.scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[contentView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:@{@"contentView":self.contentView}]];
```

The first `layoutIfNeeded` is because the size was returning a width of 600 (default in Interface Builder) and this seemed to be throwing off the rest of the sizing.

However, my main issue is that during `viewDidLoad` the size returns correct for scrollView and contentView. Then if I call the following function from within `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)renderStreams
{
    NSLog(@"Scroll View: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.scrollView.frame.size));
    NSLog(@"Content View: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.contentView.frame.size));
```

It works fine, the sizes return correctly. However, my code makes a call to another class which loads my data asynchronously and fires a notification. In my current class I call the renderStreams function like so:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
{
     [self renderStreams];
});
```

Now when I check the scrollView size it has changed from 391 to 375. And more oddly, the contentView has changed to 0,0.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Sizes are meaningless in `viewDidLoad`, and should not be queried or set in that method. The view layout is not computed until *after* `viewDidLoad` returns. Any code related to layout should be in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

Comment: I checked the sizing in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but the contentView is constantly returning 0,0. Even with the constrains laid out as above.